# Posting data to a controller extension method

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, commandbutton

I have the following controller which has a `CheckValidLicense` method on it:

```
public class LicenseActivationController {
    ...
    public static Boolean CheckValidLicense(String activationId, String username, String password) {
        ...
    }
}
```

In my Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="LicenseActivationController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="License Activation">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:outputLabel value="Username:" for="username"/>
                <apex:inputText value="{!username}" id="username" />
                <apex:outputLabel value="Password:" for="password"/>
                <apex:inputText value="{!password}" id="password" />
                <apex:outputLabel value="Activation ID:" for="activationID"/>
                <apex:inputText value="{!activationID}" id="activationID" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Activate" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

How can I post the `username`, `password`, and `activationID` up into the `CheckValidLicense` once the user hits the `Activate` button? I haven't been able to find examples of how to do this (or even something like this) with Visualforce Pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, you need a class method that returns a `PageReference` in order to associate it to the `commandButton`.  You'll also want to have some class variables to bind the input fields to:

```
public class LicenseActivationController {
    public string activationId {get; set;}
    public string userName {get; set;}
    public string password {get; set;}

    public PageReference doLicenseCheck()
    {
        if (checkValidLicense(activationId, userName, password))
        {
            return Page.LicenseSuccess; //Example of redirecting
        }
        else
        {
            return null; //Posts back to the page.
        }
    }

    public static Boolean CheckValidLicense(String activationId, String username, String password) {
        ...
    }
}
```

On your Visualforce page, update your `commandButton` with an `action` attribute pointing at the new method:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Activate" action="{!doLicenseCheck}" />
```

Now when you hit the command button, it will call the `doLicenseCheck` method and either redirect or post back depending on what you return.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are using JS remoting you need to use class properties:

```
public string activationId {get; set;}
public string userName {get; set;}
public string password {get; set;}

public static Boolean CheckValidLicense() {
        ...
}
```

You could also use `<apex:param name="userName" value="YOURVALUE">` in the commandButton block and then user `apexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('userName')` for example but I prefer the previous way

Comment: Thanks Eric. Just a quick follow up - how does the form know to post back to the `CheckValidLicense` action?

Comment: @Alexandru - It is the method that is called by the command button using the action attribute if you desire